# Convert console application to gui

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I wrote an application in lazarus, I didn't need a gui at that time so I choose Console Application, I changed the output to Win32 because I didn't want the black window to be displayed.

Now I am trying to add a form to my application but I am getting the error : Error: identifier idents no member "CreateForm"

I know it's because the application has some console origins but I don't know how to change mode to win32 gui. I tried setting different WidgetSet, no result what so ever.

Any tips?

Comment: Create a blank GUI application and move your original code into there. Or study the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add unit forms to the uses, and add a dependency on "LCL" to the project.